# Как в GoogleMap API for Android добавить шкалу масштаба?

Tags: android, google-maps-api

Нужно к GoogleMap добавить шкалу масштаба, как на веб-версии карты.[image: Эта шкала выделена красным овалом на скриншоте]

Comment: Google Maps API v2 не дает доступ к шкале, как и к темному фону

Comment: @iFr0z а возможно ли организовать свою шкалу, используя `googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom`?

Comment: Примерно то, что мне нужно нашёл [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852773/how-to-show-the-scale-bar-and-zom-controls-on-the-map)